# SOLVED - Outlook 2021 asking for credential after upgrading from outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2021

When upgrading from office 2010 to 2021 and open outlook I get a popup asking for credential but it shouldn't ask that since it's already connected to Microsoft Exchange, I can see behind the popup that outlook is working perfectly. Is there a way to remove that popup?

[screenshot showing "connected to exchange" with the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SvWT.png)

Also the popup is showing the username@domain and not the email. **When entering the correct credentials, outlook is working fine**, no more popup. It shouldn't be a problem for few users but **I have to deploy that upgrade for more than 1000 computers**. A lot of users will have troubles to make it work. I need to make that pop up disappear.

So I need two solutions : Either remove the popup or change the default value for login (the user email instead of the username@domain)
The first solution is what I look for since it doesn't require any action from the user.

I already tried to clear outlook caches ( delete %localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache and %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect ) but the popup is still present.

EDIT: I forgot to add while I get that popup asking for credentials, I also get a lot of popup regarding autodiscover.xml Maybe it's related? Those popup are also gone when I enter the correct logins.

EDIT2: Problem solved by adding a dword "**ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint**" containing 1 in the key **HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover**

Comment: What’s your question? Enter your credentials into the prompt. If you do does it go away?

Comment: @Ramhound: His problem is how to do that for 1000 computers.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you are connecting to O365/Exchange Online. What I don't understand is, how did this work when on Outlook 2010? I am not 100% certain, but I don't think Outlook 2010 works with Office365/EXO. Has this upgrade from Outlook versions also coincided with migrating your email from on-prem to Exchange Online (EXO)?

The other indicator you are in O365 is when you say the username is xx@domain and not the email address. This likely the UPN (google it). please answer these questions to provide more info so we can help

Comment: Are you using Microsoft 365 and are all your computers inside one domain? Is modern authentication enabled in Exchange or do you use basic authentication? Are the users logged-on to their computer with a user account that is a member of a domain trusted by the Exchange Server computer? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @Mucker It only happens on outlook 2021, I don't have that popup with office 2010. Basicaly I just installed Office LTSC 2021 and it automatically uninstalled office 2010 to replace it with Office LTSC 2021. About the migrating email from on-prem to Exchange Online, I'm not sure I will have to ask the administrators.

Comment: @harrymc The company uses O365 but only for VIP users. For common users we used Office 2010 and now we want to upgrade to office LTSC 2021.The screenshot provided is from Outlook2021.Yes all computer are inside the same domain. For the other question I will have to ask my administrators

Comment: Outlook autodiscover might be trying to login to Office 365, rather than to external non O365 credentials. See if adding `ExcludeExplicitO36` to the registry can stop this behavior. [This link](https://www.jucra.com/whmcs/knowledgebase/200/Prevent-Office365-from-prioritising-office-accounts-over-external-IMAP-accounts-during-set-up.html) has explanation and how to set the registry.

Comment: @harrymc - My employer handles it by allowing users to enter the information. My employer has tens of thousands of employees. The prompt is due to Outlook auto discovery of Exchange 365 backend. Question of course does not all the relevant facts.

Comment: If it is related to autodiscover, it's suggested that you could try to add "ExcludeHttpsAutodiscoverDomain"=dword:00000001 to  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover]. (Note: Serious problems can occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before making changes, back up the registry(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) to restore it in case something goes wrong.)

Comment: @harrymc This works thank you so much. My only issue now it that it's only working for the current user, the same issue will appear for new users of the computer. That problem should be solved with a GPO, I will have a meetings with the admins.

Comment: @Christy Thank you for your answer, the problem is solved with ExcludeExplicitO36 set to 1

Comment: I added an answer. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Outlook autodiscover is trying to login to Office 365,
rather than using the external non-O365 credentials that are used
by your non-VIP users.

The solution is to add the item `ExcludeExplicitO36` to the registry
which will stop this behavior.

This command can do the required registry update (`x` stands for your
Office version, probably `16`) :

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover /t REG_DWORD /v ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint /d 1
```

Setting this registry item for all non-VIP users is best done by the
domain administrator.

For more information see the article
[Prevent Office365 from prioritising office accounts over external IMAP accounts during set up](https://www.jucra.com/whmcs/knowledgebase/200/Prevent-Office365-from-prioritising-office-accounts-over-external-IMAP-accounts-during-set-up.html).

Comment: Although this seems to be the fix, isn't Outlook going to O365 for autodiscover caused by the customer pointing their autodiscover records to O365 though? At least this is how you used to it. For example, let's say we completely removed the autodisover DNS records, wouldn't it not go to O365 also? in other words, can this not be resolved by fixing up the autodiscover records also, or is that new feature (in the link) going to a generic O365 autodiscover that is completely out of the customers control?

Comment: @Mucker: The problem in this company is that there a mix of users using O365 and ones that are not.

Comment: I am aware of that, I know how Hybrid works (What you are describing). I have set it up several times, which is why I put a detailed comment. My point is that, if the autodiscover is configured incorrectly, this should be fixed, rather than avoiding autodiscover. All good, no point getting bogged down in the comments